# Getting activerecord readonly error when adding a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two queries for two different pages:

```
all_teams = Team.includes(:terms, :labs, people: [:schools], term_enrollments: [:lab])
current_teams = Team.includes(:terms, :labs, people: [:schools], term_enrollments: [:lab]).where(terms: {id: 3)
```

I am trying to update the term_enrollments with each query.  For the first query, everything is good.  I do this with the first query:

```
a = all_teams.first.term_enrollments.first
a.update_attributes term: Term.find(2)
=> true
```

When I try to do this with the second query, it doesn't work.  Here's the code I try to do for the second query:

```
a = current_teams.first.term_enrollments.first
a.update_attributes term: Term.find(2)
```

But instead of working it says:

```
ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord: TermEnrollment is marked as readonly
```

Both of these queries are in controller actions and feed a page that loops through the activerecord relation and shows an edit form for each instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_teams` is probably doing some `join` which in some cases causes the records to become readonly. You can get around this with

```
a = all_teams.first.term_enrollments.first.readonly(false)
a.update_attributes(term: Term.find(2))
```